# inserting subclasses into a superclasses array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, pointers, subclass

This is one of those things where i just know im doing it wrong. My assignment is simple.

Create 3 classes in c++,

product ,software ,book. product is super, book and software are product.
then make an array of pointers and fill the array with software and books.

so i've done the following

```
int main()
{
 Product *productList[10];          


 Book *pBook;                       
 Book q(5);
 pBook = &q;
 pBook->getPrice();

 Software *pSoftware;
 Software g(5);
 pSoftware = &g;
 pSoftware ->getPrice();


 productList[0] = pSoftware; // fill it with software, cannot do this.
```

Is there any way of inserting a subclass into a super classes array. Or should i define the array of pointers as something else.

class definitions below

```
class Product
{
public:

double price;

double getPrice();

Product::Product(double price){};
};


class Book: public Product
{
public:
Book::Book(double price)
    :Product(price)
{
}
double getPrice();
};

class Software: public Product
{
public:
Software::Software(double price)
    :Product(price)                 // equivalent of super in java?
{
}                                   // code of constructor goes here.
double getPrice();
};
```

Comment: Is this C or C++? I guess this is obviously C++. Use a `std::vector` instead of an array

Comment: Can you show us the definitions of the `Product`, `Book`, and `Software` classes? You should be able to put all three types of pointers into a `Product *` array if `Book` and `Software` are all subtypes of `Product`.

Comment: @Falmarri   it says c++ in the title.

Comment: @OVERTONE: Yes, but you're using arrays instead of `std::vector`, which is why I asked.

Comment: because that was the assignment. I've onyl barely touched on vecotrs, this is only an introduction to inheritance. if it helps ill add c++ to the question.

Comment: @Falmarri: There really isn't much advantage to using vectors in place of static arrays.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so, please tag it correctly.

Comment: @JimR wellnot really, more so some stuff i skipped because i was sick. closer to revision actually. should i still retag it?

Comment: @OVERTONE: No need to retag if it's not homework.  I just choose to skip homework questions and really don't like to use the retag ability. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the array is of type `Product`, you should declare `pSoftware` as a pointer to `Product`:

```
Product *pSoftware = new Software(5);
// ...
productList[0] = pSoftware;
```

Comment: This should be functionally identical to the OP's original code if Software inherits publicly from Product.

Comment: conversion to inaccesible base class product is not allowed. never seen this one before. gonna take a look online.

Comment: @Alan: Not quite. This is actually allocating space for the product objects that won't be destroyed when they're out of scope. OP is asking for trouble by assigning references to local variables.

Answer (score 4):

You should use public inheritance:

```
class Book : public Product {
...
};
```

**[edit]**

You should also declare `getPrice()` as virtual if you want to implement it differently in the child classes. This will make compiler call `getPrice()` of the right child class when you call `getPrice()` for a pointer to a `Product`:

```
virtual double getPrice();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but what's the default inheritance type in C++? Should

```
class Book:Product
{
```

be

```
class Book: public Product
{
```

It's always a good idea to be explicit anyway.

Comment: im here to learn :D thanks for that. im used to using extends in java, didnt know they had to be public. thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just cast the software* to a product* to put it in your array?
    productList[0] = (Product*)pSoftware;